# Struggling in importing matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: matplotlib, pip, python-3.8

I'm started learning python recently. As the part of that I started learning **DATA VISUALIZATION USING PYPLOT**.
But while importing **matplotlib.pylot** in my code It showing an error. I've searched for the solution in online as much as possible but I can't get the solution.

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

while using this it showing the error message as follow

```
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\Sarwesh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 174, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  File "C:\Users\Sarwesh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 159, in _check_versions
    from . import ft2font
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing ft2font: The specified module could not be found.
```

I've also reinstalled matplotlib

```
C:\Users\Sarwesh>pip show matplotlib
Name: matplotlib
Version: 3.3.2
Summary: Python plotting package
Home-page: https://matplotlib.org
Author: John D. Hunter, Michael Droettboom
Author-email: matplotlib-users@python.org
License: PSF
Location: c:\users\sarwesh\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages
Requires: numpy, python-dateutil, pyparsing, pillow, kiwisolver, certifi, cycler
Required-by:
```

"I'm having python-3.8 in my system"

Since I'm a beginner in python please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get the solution.
I just updated my Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable  package
you can get it [here](https://www.techspot.com/downloads/6776-visual-c-redistributable-package.html)
I hope that it will helpful to people those who struggling like me.